# Loop, push method and Subarrays in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, push

This seem pretty basic but I can't figure out why I get an error here.
I'm trying to insert variables into a subarrays based on a loop, that gathers variables from the website (my_vars["content"].

Here's how it looks :

```
    MyStuff.Track({
       Game: new Array()

    });

    Game.push({
            for (i=0; i< my_vars["content"].length; i++) 
                    {
            id : my_vars["content"][i].ID,
            price : my_vars["content"][i].price,
            quantity : my_vars["content"][i].quantity

                    }

                })
```

For some reason I always get the same error :
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

It must be obvious but I can't see it.

Thanks a lot,

Hugo

Comment: On which line is it giving this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push functions expects elements as param.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

You could use

```
for (i=0; i< my_vars["content"].length; i++) {
    Game.push({
        id : my_vars["content"][i].ID,
        price : my_vars["content"][i].price,
        quantity : my_vars["content"][i].quantity
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer I understand the issue ! However I still have a problem trying to insert this in the parent array :

MyStuff.Track({
       Game: new Array()

    });

It says Game is undefined. I guess I understand why, but I can't figure out how to insert it there.

Comment: I've assumed you declared the Game array before the loop. Declare it just before the for loop.

Comment: Well it is, should I do it differently ?

MyStuff.Track({
       Game: new Array()

    });

for (i=0; i< my_vars["content"].length; i++) {
    Game.push({
        id : my_vars["content"][i].ID,
        price : my_vars["content"][i].price,
        quantity : my_vars["content"][i].quantity
    });
}

Comment: I think you're a bit off here. If you want MyStuff.Track as an object then you should declare like this..

MyStuff.Track = { Game: [] };
MyStuff.Track.Game.push....

If you edit the post with the declaration of MyStuff and Track then that'll be helpful.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, i'd have done this too but the issue is that's coming directly from a partner's minimized library and I have no control over it. I'll try to see what's missing with him. Thanks a lot man, much appreciated.